# Python functions in sqlite select statements, is this possible?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I am trying to see if sqlite3 can be used in association with custom Python function in select statement.

I am trying to figure out if something like this is possible.

```
select my_custom_python_function(b.name), b.id, b.country from my_table b
```

my_custom_python_function is a custom python function that I wanted to create. This is similar to any existing sqlite3 functions. e.g. isnull, printf

I could not find any documentation to do this. Any inputs would be appreciated.

I am using sqlite 3.8.3 and python 3.6, I am upgrade if needed if this is not possible with current releases.

Comment: Read the python sqlite binding documentation again, because the answer is in it.

Answer (score 2):

You can call python function from sqlite query.
Just use create_function("sql_name", no_of_arguments, python_function)

Example:

```
import sqlite3

def returnTopRank(students_rank, threshold):
    return students_rank < threshold

db = sqlite3.connect("my.db")
db.create_function("sql_returnTopRank", 2, returnTopRank)
query = "SELECT rank FROM students WHERE sql_returnTopRank(students.rank, 10)"
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute(query)
```

In above example, "create_function" links the python function with sql database, which can be called from anywhere inside query.

You can modify above example to use in yours.

I hope this helps.